# Php Photos Edit

Tags: php, image, png, jpeg

Hello i have a folder with a 3000 photos and i need a script that add my site logo buttom the image, i have script to edit images but i need a one that open images and make the procces,

my script

```
<?php
        $logo = imagecreatefrompng("logo.png");

        header('Content-type: image/jpg');

        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.jpg");

        imagecopy($image, $logo, 132, 95, 0, 0, 25, 25);

        imagejpeg($image);

        imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

also if anybody have a program for windows please send to me.

Comment: Adobe Lightroom and Photoshop let you do this rather easily

Comment: how do you have any toturial or any demo

Comment: Photoshop has batch processing in File - Automate. In Lightroom it's just to export the files with a watermark, it's an export option

Comment: Why don't you increase your current script?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
function add_png_logo(){
    $dir = APPPATH.'assets/img/'; # Where your PNG photos are
    $dirUpload = APPPATH.'assets/uploads/'; # Where they will be saved
    $baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1/tests/assets/uploads/'; # Base to link merged images
    # Where the work begins
    $iteractor = new DirectoryIterator($dir);
    $ext = ['png'];
    $i = 0;
    # Function to save individual files
    function save_png($getFilename,$getFilePath){
        $medida = array('width'=>'1024','height'=>'1024',);
        // Creates a temp image
        $TempPngFile = imagecreatetruecolor($medida['width'], $medida['height']);
        # Defines a transparent color to fill all image
        $TransparentColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($TempPngFile, 0, 0, 0, 127);
        imagefill($TempPngFile, 0, 0, $TransparentColor);
        # Forces transparency definition
        imagealphablending($TempPngFile, true);
        imagesavealpha($TempPngFile, true);
        # Open image
        $logo = imageCreateFromPng(APPPATH.'cache/mark.png');
        # Fix transparency definitions
        imageAlphaBlending($logo, true);
        imageSaveAlpha($logo, true);            
        # Open image
        $img2 = imageCreateFromPng($getFilename);
        # Forces transparency definition
        imageAlphaBlending($img2, true);
        imageSaveAlpha($img2, true);
        # insert $logo and $img2 in $TempPngFile and setting positioning
        imagecopy($TempPngFile, $img2, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($img2), imagesy($img2));
        imagecopy($TempPngFile, $logo, 25, 25, 0, 0, imagesx($logo), imagesy($logo)); 
        # Save final image to $getFilePath
        imagepng($TempPngFile, $getFilePath);
        // Destroy images
        imageDestroy($TempPngFile);
        imageDestroy($logo);
        imageDestroy($img2);            
    }
    # Loop in $dir, get all PNG files to overlap $logo on left top
    foreach ($iteractor as $entry) {
        if ($entry->isFile()) {
            if (in_array($entry->getExtension(), $ext)) {
                $getFilename = $dir.$entry->getFilename();
                $getImageName = $entry->getFilename().'_'.$i++.'_.png';
                $getFilePath = $dirUpload.$getImageName;
                save_png($getFilename, $getFilePath);
                echo 'Created image: <a href="'.$baseUrl.$getImageName.'" target="_blank">'.$getImageName.'</a><br>';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OBS:** It uses the `php-gd` extension. And certainlly there is a way to convert JPG to PNG before overlap the files (or you should first convert your 3000 photos to PNG), but I'm too lazy now, and it works! And now it's on your hands!